# Loading image while progress bar loads

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gallery

I want to have an async task that loads images from the drawable folder. How could i display a progress bar in another xml? I want to display the images in gallery.

How do I go about doing it?
** It would be helpful if you use the hello gallery code**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to show a progress bar, you have to create a globar variable to reference the progress bar.

```
ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
```

Then, in the asynk task use the default methods to handle the progressBar

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    //create the dialog
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getBaseContext(), "Tittle","Description");
};      
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{   
    //load the image  
    return null;
}       
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    //dismiss te dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
};
```

If you want to use a percent bar you can also use the method

```
onProgressUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

In async task

send a progressbar(which one you want to update) to asynctask's constructor,In the method doBackground,loading your picture and use method publisProgress(maybe named this,just alt + /),last,updating your progressbar in this method..

Comment: okay, now i understand the general concept behind. One more question i have a gallery.java       
With the code below, I am able to load another file (Asynctask.java)
new LoadingScreenActivity(image, progressBar,     mImages[position]).execute();
how am i suppose to write the AsyncTask.java ? cos i am totally clueless.

Comment: You means that you are using  (gallery.java)  to loading picture and use (Asynctask.java) to updating progressbar? you could also loading picture in (Asynctask.java)

Comment: At first, i did not know that asynctask works this way, i though they are two different seperate code like gallery is gallery and loading screen is loading screen. 
Now, i trying to use the asynctask.java to show a loading screen while loading the gallery images, which is in the drawable folder

Comment: Wish you success sincerely  ^_^